# ¿como se puede usar Symfony Panther para test en modo docker?

Tags: docker, symfony

La consigna es, se tiene un proyecto symfony en docker, tambien se tiene el panther para test de modulos en docker, pero los test de levantar el navegador solo funcionan en modo local, usando la llamada desde el entorno del equipo host y no desde el docker que solo levanta el navegador pero no ejecuta el test del formulario, lo que se quiere evitar es que al realizar el traspaso entre ambientes (desarrolo a produccion) se eviten problemas de version como el de PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tutorial bastante util: [Utilizar Docker con WSL 2 en Windows 10](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2020/06/04/utilizar-docker-con-wsl-2-en-windows-10/) complementado con este otro [Cuál es la forma más fácil de ejecutar aplicaciones GUI en Windows Subsystem para Linux a partir de 2018](https://www.web-dev-qa-db-esp.com/es/gui/cual-es-la-forma-mas-facil-de-ejecutar-aplicaciones-gui-en-windows-subsystem-para-linux-partir-de-2018/960697061/)